# Print preview page as a popup using Jasper reports with ADF

Tags: jasper-reports, oracle-adf

How do I display the print preview page as a popup?

I tried a code from the net but it takes me to another page.

```
            HttpServletResponse response = getResponse();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        ServletContext context = getContext();
        InputStream reportStream = context.getResourceAsStream("report-templates/TestReport.jasper");

        if (reportStream == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Input stream is null");
        }

        JasperReport jasperTemplate = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(reportStream);
        jasperTemplate.setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataTypeEnum.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL);
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperTemplate, record,conn);

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, baos);

        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
        baos.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
        baos.close();
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

What changes do I make here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

Create a servlet in your application and write your code in its doGet method. Add a popup component on your page. Open this popup from the button/link, which you are using to execute your code. 
Invoke the servlet using inlineFram in the poup window.

```
<af:popup id="popupReport" animate="default" 
          contentDelivery="lazyUncached">
    <af:panelWindow id="pw1" modal="true" title="Sample Report" 
                    contentHeight="625" contentWidth="700" resize="on">
        <af:inlineFrame id="if1" shortDesc="Report inline frame" 
                        source="/showreportservlet"
                        syleClass="AFStretchWidth"
                        inlineStyle="height:500px;">
        </af:inlineFrame>
</af:panelWindow>
```

Assuming `/showreportservlet` is the url pattern specified while creating the servlet